# Binding a property of a relative source root parent control to an attached property of a child class - crash the app

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-binding

I am trying to bind an attached property of an `Entry` control to a property of it root parent which is a `ContentView`:
(Mainly to use/access the ViewModel(BindingContext) of the called view in the `NumBehaviors` class)
The application crashes before even starting without clear spot of the problem in the debug:

> Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

> At Xamarin.Forms.Binding.ApplyRelativeSourceBinding (Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject targetObject, Xamarin.Forms.BindableProperty targetProperty) [0x00041] in D:\a\1\s\Xamarin.Forms.Core\ [Binding.cs:153](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/blob/17881ec93d6b3fb0ee5e1a2be46d7eeadef23529/Xamarin.Forms.Core/Binding.cs#L153)

> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.

1- Am I doing something wrong (maybe with `BindingContext`)?  Or it is Xamarin still not handling bindings as good as wpf (like the lack of `ElementName`) ?

2- Why the debug error/exceptions are not so explicit ?

**MainView.xaml**:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:Helpers="clr-namespace:App.Helpers"
             xmlns:Behaviors="clr-namespace:App.Behaviors"
             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
             VerticalOptions="Center"
             x:Class="App.Views.MainView">

<Entry>
     <Entry.Behaviors>
          <Behaviors:NumBehaviors Helpers:HelperClass.Vm=
           "{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentView}}, Path=VM}"/>
     </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

**HelperClass.cs**

```
public static BindableProperty VmProperty = 
       BindableProperty.Create("Vm", typeof(object), typeof(HelperClass), null);

public static object GetVm(BindableObject bindable)
{
    return (object)bindable.GetValue(VmProperty);
}

public static void SetVm(BindableObject bindable, object value)
{
    bindable.SetValue(VmProperty, value);
}
```

**MainView.cs**

```
public object VM {get; set;}

public MainView()
{
InitializeComponent();
VM  = (object) new MyViewModel();
BindingContext = VM;
}
```

**NumBehaviors.cs**

```
...
void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args) {
     var usedvm = HelperClass.GetVm((BindableObject)sender);
}
```

---

I could maybe use the following but I think it is a bad idea, it is useless when the `BindingContext` of `Entry` is different from the one of it root parent also it does not look flexible:

```
...
void OnEntryTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs args) {
     var usedvm = ((Entry)sender).BindingContext;
}
```

PS:
Maybe my approach is not good, I am open to better approaches to achieve that.

**EDIT**

Using *Xamarin.Forms 4.8.0.1364*

Also tried with `AncestorType={x:Type local:MainView}}` instead of `AncestorType={x:Type ContentView}}` gave the same result.

Maybe it is related to this opened issue of Xamarin.Forms [[Bug] Compiled bindings not working when using AncestorType #9839](https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/9839)

Comment: We could follow the details on Github the link you provided.

Comment: Related: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183883/behavior-crashes-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object

Comment: @ClayBrooks It is working can you put it as an answer so that I will accept it, also I believe I made a mistake `Helpers:HelperClass.Vm..` should be an attached property of <Entry.. instead of `Entry.Behaviors:NumBehaviors` otherwise `HelperClass.GetVm((BindableObject)sender);` will always returns null unless we provide somehow `Sender.Behaviors:NumBehaviors` as a parameter instead of sender (=Entry)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another solution to avoid this issue would be simply to change the design by moving the Attached property from `<Entry.Behaviors:NumBehaviors>` to `<Entry>`:

```
<Entry Helpers:HelperClass.Vm="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContentView}},
                               Path=VM}">
     <Entry.Behaviors>
          <Behaviors:NumBehaviors/>
     </Entry.Behaviors>
</Entry>
```

This move will also fix the mistake I made in my question code, I was attaching the property `Vm` to the object `<Entry.Behaviors:NumBehaviors>` while I was trying to get it from object `Sender(=Entry)` (`var usedvm = HelperClass.GetVm((BindableObject)sender);`) which would always returns `null`.

Comment: I am glad to know that you resolve the issue by yourself and share your solution to us, it would be benficial to other communities who have the similar issue if you accept it as answer.

Answer (score 3):

`RelativeSource` can find its ancestor's binding context but behaviors are not in the current visual tree.

I suggest using this to indicate the binding context:

```
Command="{Binding BindingContext.YourCommand, Source={x:Reference PageName}}"
```

`YourCommand` must be accessible from `BindingContext` and `PageName` must be set in the attributes of the enclosing `ContentPage` like `<ContentPage ... x:Name="PageName"`

More details can be found [here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/183883/behavior-crashes-operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-state-of-the-object).  Props to the guy from that link who gave the initial solution.

Comment: Could you please adapt your solution into a working answer to the question example context so that users won't get confused ? and most important what will be the parameter object for  `GetVm()` in this case